# setState in handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, jsx, setstate

I have the following `handleSubmit()` function which is called `onSubmit` of a form:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state))
    if(this.validateForm())
        this.props.history.push("/work?mins="+this.state.minutes+"&interest="+this.interestsInitials())
    // the following line breaks everyhting
    this.setState({...this.state, pressedEnter: true})
}
```

`validateForm` is another function that attempts at making changes to the state:

```
handleChanges = (e, changeName) => {
    switch (changeName) {
        case "minutes": 
            this.setState({...this.state, minutes: e.target.value})
            break
        case "business":
            this.setState({...this.state, interests:{...this.state.interests, business: e.target.checked} })
            break
        // ...
        default:
            console.log("Cannot identify the input")               
    }
}
```

My fear is that calling `setState` so close to each other breaks everything. Is this true?

Notice that `handleSubmit` is called in the following markup:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="business" checked={ this.state.interests.business }
                       onChange={ (e) => this.handleChanges(e, "business") }/>
```

Comment: Can you provide the error? Also, can you show how/where you are calling the `handleSubmit` method?

Comment: The inputs become unresponsive, they don't change the status anymore. I do not get any errors as such in the console. I'll add the tag I'm calling the function from in my question.

Comment: Hmm well I'm a little unsure of the context here then. Any way you can provide a fiddle example with something that recreates the problem?

Comment: You do not need to expand `...this.state` when calling `this.setState`. If you pass an Object as the first argument to `setState`, it performs a shallow merge with the current state. I don't think it will affect performance significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `this.setState({...this.state})` is even valid, and there should be better alternatives:

```
// Only pass new changes
this.setState({ minutes: e.target.value });

// When things get a bit nested & messy
const interests = this.state.interests; // Might need to clone instead of direct assignment
interests.business = e.target.checked;
this.setState({ interests });
```

You can also pass a callback to setState like this:

```
this.setState({ minutes: e.target.value }, () => {
  // this callback is called when this setState is completed and the component is re-rendered
  // do more calculations here & safely set the new state changes
  const newState = { minutes: 12 };
  this.setState(newState);
});
```

To avoid calling setState(s) so closely, you can let `validateForm` return state changes in form of a object, extends `pressedEnter: true` to it then call one final setState for all changes, or just using a callback like so:

```
handleChanges = (e, changeName, cb) => {
  const newState = this.state; // Might need to clone instead of direct assignment
  switch (changeName) {
    case "minutes": 
        newState.minutes = e.target.value; break;
    case "business":
        newState.interests.business = e.target.checked; break;
    //...
    default:
        console.log("Cannot identify the input"); break;           
  }
  cb(newState);
}
```

`cb` can be something like this:

```
function(newState) {
  newState.pressedEnter = true;
  // Make sure "this" is referring to the component though
  this.setState(newState);
};
```

If things get too messy, just convert the above callback into a component's method.

Comment: Thanks it works. How can I avoid to use the spread operator when updating nested objects without creating a temporary variable e.g. `this.setState({interests:{...this.state.interests, design: e.target.checked}}, this.checkErrorsAgain )`

Comment: If what's you're looking for is a single code line then this might work too: `this.setState(prevState => ({ interests: Object.assign(prevState.interests, { design: e.target.checked })), callback);` but using a temporary variable is always easier to read and change later I suppose: `const interests = this.state.interests; interests.design = e.target.checked; this.setState({ interests }, callback);`

Comment: Remember to clone objects from last state instead of using direct assignments though. I don't know what libraries you're using so I omit that part to make the code a bit clearer. You can do something like `const interests = _.cloneDeep(this.state.interests);` with *lodash* or even use *immutable* for React components' state (my recommendation!).

Comment: Ok but there is no gain from using `Object.assign` vs the spread operator so I think I'll stick with the spread operator.

Comment: Yeah, probably should stick to things that you can read faster and prefer :)